# Binance hacked?

Tags: blockchain, exchanges, security, hack

Something is happening, yesterday in reddit many people could not withdraw their funds or cancel their purchase orders .
And the administrator (who is binance and usually solves the problems) erased the posts.And today for more than an hour they arent trading because they are "keeping the servers" without warning before.  What happened?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I have found a few comments on this and will answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From [`@binance_2017`](https://twitter.com/binance_2017) on Twitter:

00:34 AM - 8 Feb 2018 UTC

A system maintenance is in progress, some users may experience a temporary decrease in exchange performance while this in underway.Thank you for your understanding.— binance (@binance_2017) [February 8, 2018](https://twitter.com/binance_2017/status/961397899241254914?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

And [support.binance.com](https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000713851):

> #### Fellow Binancians,
>
> Due to a significant increase in users and trading activity, Binance will need to extend the System upgrade and is expected to be completed by 2PM (UTC).
>
> Our team is working hard to complete this upgrade as quickly as possible. We will make an announcement to all users if completed ahead of schedule.
>
> Withdrawals and trading during this period will remain suspended. We apologize for any inconvenience caused and thank you for your patience.
>
> Thank you for your support.
>
> Binance Team
>
> 2018/02/08

Answer (score 1):

Bianance was not hacked - so they report. see -
 https://www.ft.com/content/c17f9cae-0caf-11e8-8eb7-42f857ea9f09

Twitter Post:
binance
‏
Verified account

@binance_2017
28 minutes ago
More binance Retweeted CZ
-Due to an unforeseen slowdown in the speed of our data sync, we now estimate for all trading activity to resume at 2018/02/09 4AM (UTC). In the 30 minutes prior to the commencement of trading, users will be able to use utilize all other account related functions.